# Find max and second max salary for a employee table MySQL not calculated by digit

Tags: mysql

[image]

I want 2nd max salary from this table

```
mysql> select * from Employee;                                                                                                                                          
+------+---------+--------+                                                                                                                                             
| id   | name    | salary |                                                                                                                                             
+------+---------+--------+                                                                                                                                             
| 1    | shubham | 200    |                                                                                                                                             
| 2    | geeta   | 300    |                                                                                                                                             
| 3    | nir     | 500    |                                                                                                                                             
| 4    | pooja   | 2000   |                                                                                                                                             
| 5    | pranav  | 5000   |                                                                                                                                             
+------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: What should happen if there is a tie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this query to get 2nd highest salary

`SELECT  * FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary  DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`

Comment: @shubhamjadhav what is the datatype of salary? If it is not `int`  than run `ALTER TABLE Employee ALTER COLUMN Saray int;` and then run `SELECT  * FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary  DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `docs` (
      `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(4)  NOT NULL,
      `salary` int(10) Unsigned NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

This should be your schema for database.

now execute, 
SELECT  * FROM Employee ORDER BY Salary  DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1

Comment: @shubhamjadhav Better use `SELECT  * FROM Employee ORDER BY CAST(Salary as SIGNED INTEGER)  DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`. If you are storing integer values only, better use `int` datatype otherwise varchar gives wrong result. CAST can help but remember that on large database it kills performance.

Comment: glad it worked...upvote and mark the ans correct if you like it.